# Calculating the area between three tangent circles of unit radius, and using the result to show $\pi^2<12$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Diagram shows three circles, each of radius 1cm, centres A, B, and C. Each circle touches the other two.

From here you can get the area of triangle ABC:

Height of equilateral triangle ABC: $h = \sqrt{2^2 - 1^2} = \sqrt3$

Area of equilateral triangle ABC: $A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot\sqrt3 = \sqrt3$

Area of single circle: $C = \pi\cdot 1^2 = \pi$

Circle sector has angle 60deg (angles in equilateral triangle)

Therefore area of single circle sector $S = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Area of shaded region: SW $= S = \sqrt3 - \frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 3 = \sqrt3 - \frac{\pi}{2}$

> From the area of the shaded region, prove that $\pi^2 < 12$.

Possible i've miscalculated the shaded region area, but i'm not sure how one relates to the other, any pointers?

Comment: $\sqrt3-\frac{\pi}{2}>0$, $\sqrt3>\frac{\pi}{2}$,$3>(\frac{\pi}{2})^2$,$\pi^2<12$

Comment: Clear and concise, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not even bother with the shaded area except to note it's strictly positive. Thus the area of the full triangle $\sqrt3$ is greater than the area of the three sectors $\pi/2$.